# Packaging Django code for deployment

Tags: python, django, deployment

I'm getting ready to move my Django project from my laptop to my server.  What is the recommended way to do this?  E.g., is there a Django command that will package everything up (and select the correct settings file for test vs prod servers) and create a zip or tar file that can be moved over to the server?  Sort of like Ant for building Java projects.

Comment: really good guide for heroku `https://www.dropbox.com/s/68sc3ihna7qdaiu/test.py` and video for it `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kvTsCskJA0`

Comment: It seems a lot of the tutorials are geared toward Heroku or other 3rd party hosting but I'm using RHEL and am essentially building the server environment from the ground up, hence the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using virtual environment for your Django project.

`source bin/activate` your virtual environment in your server would simulate the same setup as of your local.

#### In your project

1. List all your dependencies in `requirements.txt` and settings in `my_settings.py` apart from django settings.py

#### In your server

2. just pull/transfer your code via git or any other means and activate virtual environment.
3. `pip install -r reuirements.txt` and change any minor changes required in `my_settings`
4. Take care of your `migrations` and Db  setup. You may have to run migrations if you are migrating to your server for the first time.

And thats it you are up and running.

Comment: I am using virtualenv so that makes sense. Is there also a way to clean an existing deployment before releasing a new version of the app?